# MySQL queries still slow after deleting bunch of records

Tags: mysql, sql, innodb, myisam

I need some help with resolving some mysql issues. My website had been running slow since last week and after contacting my host I found out that some queries were taking too long mainly because of table locks.
I am a developer but no mysql/database expert. My host suggested that I either delete and/or change the two tables in question to innoDB. So as these tables had a lot of junk data I decided to delete a bunch of records. I would say that these two tables are about 25% of the size when this problem started.
Problem is that, it still has not made any difference.
So my questions:

1. Do I need to clear cache or optimize table in order to see the
   effects? My host is still suggesting I change those tables to innoDB
   which is fine but I'm not sure why deleting that many records have
   not made a difference.
2. Also I have read that it is better to
   recreate the table than just optimizing?  If needed I can hire a
   database admin to help me but I would like to at least try a few
   things if this is something simple. Can someone please guide me
   through this.

One more important thing to add, it is a legacy website running on php 5.4 and mysql 5.6

Here is one of the sample query that locks the table.

```
SELECT `m`.`message_id`, COUNT(`m`.`message_id`) AS `mails_count`, `m`.`sender_id`, `m`.`recipient_id`, 
            `m`.`text`, `m`.`is_readable`, `m`.`time_stamp` AS `last_message_ts`, `c`.`conversation_id`, `c`.*, `ms`.`is_replied`
            FROM `mailbox_conversation` AS `c` 
            INNER JOIN (
                SELECT * FROM `mailbox_message` 
                WHERE `recipient_id`=67404  AND IF (`sender_id`!=67404, `status`='a', 1) ORDER BY `time_stamp` DESC  
            ) AS `m` ON(`m`.`conversation_id`=`c`.`conversation_id`) 
            INNER JOIN (
                SELECT `conversation_id`, IF(`sender_id`=67404,'yes','no') AS `is_replied` FROM `mailbox_message` 
                WHERE (`recipient_id`=67404 OR `sender_id`=67404) ORDER BY `time_stamp` DESC 
            ) AS `ms` ON(`ms`.`conversation_id`=`c`.`conversation_id`)
            WHERE (`c`.`initiator_id`=67404 OR `interlocutor_id`=67404)
            AND `c`.`bm_deleted` NOT IN (IF(`c`.`initiator_id`=67404, '1, 3','2, 3'))           
             AND IF (`sender_id`!=67404, `status`='a', 1)
            GROUP BY `c`.`conversation_id`
            ORDER BY `m`.`time_stamp` DESC  LIMIT 0,15;
```

Thank you!

Comment: Table locks won't affect select queries, only inserts and updates.  Are you doing inserts and updates?  Is your code actually acquiring table locks?

Comment: Please post the query you're using and the execution plan for that query. If you're not sure what that is, search this site for *MySQL execution plan*.

Comment: @TimRoberts I have not written that code so not sure. From what I see in the logs, it is mostly select queries.

Comment: One more important thing to add, it is a legacy website running on php 5.4 and mysql 5.6

Comment: If your code hasn't changed and your volume hasn't gone up, there's no reason why queries should suddenly start taking longer.  Increasing gradually over time I could understand, but not a sudden change.  I wonder if your shared host suddenly has a larger workload.

Comment: @TimRoberts I exactly had the same thought but then I'm like may be I have just hit some limits as my database keeps growing at a steady pace. I do have basic server and not a shared hosting package. I kept pushing my host with the same logic but they keep showing me these logs for these queries and tables locking. At this point im like I'll follow some of these suggestion and if still there are issues I might just have to change the host.

Comment: The also adjusted some buffer memory settings for mysql and still that it has not helped

Comment: If you're looking for help optimising the performance of your database, as distinct from optimising your code, then you might do better asking on [dba.se]

Comment: @TangentiallyPerpendicular oh thank you I did not knew about that site

Comment: There are too many possible explanations.  We must see the specific query in order to provide a specific answer.

Comment: @RickJames I posted a query for you above in my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are the things that are slowing down your complex query:

(1)

```
    GROUP BY  `c`.`conversation_id`
    ORDER BY  `m`.`time_stamp` DESC
    LIMIT  0,15;
```

It would be nice if it could read only 15 rows.  But that is not possible because the `GROUP BY` and `ORDER BY` don't match.  Furthermore, they involve multiple tables, thereby eliminating using an index.  (An `INDEX` can reference only one table.)

(2)

```
AND  IF (`sender_id`!=67404, `status`='a', 1)

(`recipient_id`=67404  OR  `sender_id`=67404)

(`c`.`initiator_id`=67404  OR  `interlocutor_id`=67404)
```

Both of those are too complex to use any index.  `OR` is a performance killer; it can sometimes be turned into a `UNION`.  (But you would need nested `UNIONs` to handle everything here.)  That if can probably be written `sender_id = 67404 or status='a'` -- it won't be faster, but it will be clearer (to me).

One case:

```
( SELECT ... from mailbox_message WHERE `recipient_id`=67404 )
UNION ALL
( SELECT ... from mailbox_message WHERE `sender_id`=67404 )
```

Needed for this `UNION`: `INDEX(recipient_id)` and `INDEX(sender_id)`.

(3)

```
JOIN ( SELECT ... )
```

This, especially when there are multiple such, is usually un-optimizable.

(4)

```
JOIN ( SELECT ... ORDER BY ... )
```

The `ORDER BY` will be ignored.  Cf `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY`.

(5)

```
SELECT *
```

If there are any bulky columns that you don't ultimately need, `*` may cost some performance.  Spell out the columns needed.

Comment: thank you. Originally I had opened this ticket to not change the query but to make improvement with other methods I mentioned in my post but that kinda would have been a band aid without addressing the underlying issue. Thanks for suggesting the changes. I will take these into account.

Comment: @sayayin - Alas, I don't think any configuration change, nor any index, will help that query.  When answering a question, I consider indexes, configuration, reformulation, schema changes, and even re-architecting.